# Visual Studio 2010 - error saying can't find class even though assembly is referenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Wondering if anyone could help with a weird problem I'm having with Visual Studio 2010...

I have a pile of projects, and on my PC everything is compiling fine and running. I checked out my solution onto a laptop, and one of my classes references an interface, "IClone" that is located in a different assembly. Now, in the code view, everything looks fine, no errors highlighted or nothing, yet the IClone reference beside the class name is in simple black text, not in light blue text, and when I go to compile it throws an error saying it cannot find the interface IClone, even though the assembly with it is referenced and included!

I have tried checking out the solution again, everything I can think of but getting no where - yet the exact same code and setup on my PC works fine!

Any help is much appreciated,
Stephen

Comment: Do you have an appropriate `using` directive as well? And is `IClone` definitely public (rather than internal)?

Comment: Yeah it definitely works, as the solution compiles and runs on my desktop PC, for some reason it refuses to compile on the laptop for some reason

Comment: Is it a project reference, or a straight file DLL reference? Is it all in a single solution? Has the interface assembly actually built?

Comment: check the 'target framework' for the projects - if calling is 'Client...' and lib isn't it could behave like that - just from reading fast this post

Comment: Everything is within the same solution - the interface IClone is in one project, a class library, and the class calling it is in another project... checked all the settings, it's definitely set to Net Framework 4 :S

Comment: that's the typical scenario for that - not just that's its '4', check if it isn't `Client Profile`. Also you need to '@' tag us to see the response (if more than one responding). And make sure that 'lib' `compiles `(and in `configuration` that it's set to automatically compile)

Comment: Sorry @NSGaga - I checked and it is not the `Client Profile`, it does compile by itself and is set to automatically compile, as I said everything works fine on my desktop PC, the Visual Studio setup on both my PC and laptop are identical as well

Comment: check the namespaces then (aside that it works in one place, that's strange - that seems like a dll-s issue of some sort) - make sure that it isn't 'picking up' some other similarly named. Things like this are usually relatively straight to trace. Start typing the IClone name fully qualified - start w/ global:: etc. (and to see if it gets other things from that lib, ns etc.).

Comment: @NSGaga - I have tried that as well, still no luck - here is a link to a screenshot showing what I mean about the odd way the class name is highlighted -

[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25952726/Untitled.png)

Strange thing as well - if I copy the IClone interface into the project it works fine, the problem is that nothing else could reference it either!

Comment: @NSGaga - I have also tried creating a brand new project in the solution, and created a class that implements IClone and it also works no problem, so I really am stumped at the minute! Checked over a few times as well and definitely no circular dependencies... I think Visual Studio just doesn't like me :(

Comment: One more thing I can think of - 're-reference' projects (remove/add references again) - I've seen project references all screwed up like that (and your `fresh` project working may suggest that). Also `clean up` and rebuild all. Check external dll-s (not copied w/ project), rereference them etc. And since it's `generic` I'm guessing you're getting the number of type params right.

Comment: Tried all of that too, even  checked out the solution again and tried it and it's exactly the same :S It's no biggie really - this is a demo for university so I may just have to do a dirty hack and copy the interface into the project to get it to work and explain the problem. Normally I wouldn't do this but I have to test another pile of stuff so sadly time is against me!

Comment: @NSGaga-mostly-inactive thanks! In my case it was the difference between the used .NET frameworks (4.6 and 4.7.1). So I upgraded the former one.

Answer (score 1):

Well turns out it was nothing to do with missing or wrong references... turns out the location I had checked the solution out to made the file paths too long so it wasn't working - moved everything to the C:\ drive and it worked again!

Although I really think by now Visual Studio should be able to pick up on this error and report it correctly...